# Resistors - proper SMD package for newbie

Tags: resistors, soldering, kicad, packages

I will be designing an Arduino shield in KiCAD.

This will be my first project in KiCAD.

Considering I am a newbie in PCB design and I will be performing the soldering, what is the correct package size to pick?

The ones offered by the website I will be buying from are:

1. 0402
2. 1206
3. 2512
4. 603
5. 805

Comment: Depends on your soldering skills. I'd start with 1206 as a beginner.  If your soldering skills are pretty good you could consider 0805 or even 0603, but a microscope helps with the smaller values if your eyesight isn't perfect.

Comment: You say you are a newbie in PCB design, but how are your soldering skills and equipment? An 0201 resistor looks the same as a 1206 on your computer screen, but it's a mite more difficult to solder.

Comment: 2512 is huge - would only be used if you need the power-handling capability, 1206 is still big, but may be a good size to start with. 0805 is the next size down, and may be a bit hard for a beginner to handle and solder.

Comment: Buy a PCB ruler with all the common footprints on it, and stare at them in actual size. [Adafruit has one](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1554) but you'll find them at Digikey, Sparkfun, ebay and amazon.

Comment: If you are a newbie at soldering, the correct answer is to start with through-hole components, not SMD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These package names are based on dimensions; 0402 is 0.04 by 0.02 inches, for instance. As a general rule of thumb, 1206 and bigger are easy to hand-solder, 0805 takes a steady hand but a bit of practice will have you doing them easily, and 0603 takes some real precision. anything smaller, I'd just give up trying.

Comment: Also make sure you use the hand_soldering pads for your footprints, otherwise the pads are smaller and much harder to work with.

Comment: @Michael And in some cases, you may want to manually enlarge the pads even further; some of KiCAD's default handsoldering footprints are barely bigger than the ones meant for reflow.

Comment: Hot tweezers and/or a bevel tip with the sides untinned REALLY help you work with pads sized for reflow. The solder bead on the bevel tip sneaks between the component and pad. The tweezers help you reposition the component so both pads are aligned an in contact. I own tweezers literally for that reason.

Comment: I agree.  A  beginner should start with 1206.  I have seen solder techs who routinely solder on an 0402 sized parts without problems as long as they had a microscope.  I have manually put on 0402 sized parts but it required more effort than I would recommend for any beginner.

Answer (score 2):

0805 is a balance between size and cost. I use 0603 because considerably cheaper than 0805 but still manageable. 1206 is good and visible but expensive. 0402 is not advised.

Comment: It's worth noting that the price differences are basically negligible until you're working with thousands of units.

Comment: @Hearth It's not that negligible. It's the difference between a $140 and $200 resistor kit or something like that. And 1206s cost a lot more.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking about individual parts, not a resistor kit.

Answer (score 2):

The extra cost of 1206 is probably insignificant if you’re only using a few devices at a few cents each.  Have a look at one and see how you feel about soldering it.  0805 is fine for hand soldering, 0603 requires a bit of skill.  0402 is awkward even if you’re quite expert.  So I’d suggest using larger parts unless you’re desperately poor or very short on space.  But certainly make the pads big enough that you can put the component where you want it and still touch the pad with your soldering iron.

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion? Buy some of each size and some prototyping adaptors to practice on. This will give you a feel for the skills involved.

You may find that 0402 (1005 metric) isn’t too bad if your hands are steady and you have decent equipment. Or, you may find that you will need to make the investment in good soldering irons (get two - makes it easier to unsolder a part) and tips.

As it is, most boards are made with 0402 now as the go-to size, with larger sizes used for bigger / higher power values as needed. 0201 (0603 metric) and 01005 are almost beyond what can be done by hand for most people, but show up in compact boards like mobile handsets and other small electronics.

For less-skilled beginners and folks with poor vision or shaky hands, 1206 (3216 metric) and 805 (2012 metric) are a bit easier.

But... bear in mind also that if you’re considering SMT passives, you’ll probably be dealing with SMT ICs as well. There’s different types to consider.

- QFP (gull-wing) packages solder fairly easily
- J-leads are a bit trickier because they’re harder to see (and thankfully are largely obsolete.)
- Leadless chip carriers can be hand soldered by skilled people but should best be applied by reflow
- BGAs require careful reflow technique

Comment: How *do* you hand-solder QFPs? I've never been able to get the hang of it.

Comment: Apply flux, use a chisel tip and swipe a bead of solder across the row. Remove any excess with solder wick.

Comment: @Hearth:  QFPs pin by pin.  Seriously.

Comment: @Hearth I had a soldering tech show me his trick to solder QFPs. He tacked one pin down to hold the chip in place. Then he held a piece of thin solder wire along an entire edge of the chip (the edge closest to him), at the joints where the pins hit the pcb. Imagine holding the solder with your left hand so that the end of the solder wire is at the rightmost pin. Then, _without moving the solder wire_, he simply touched the end of each pin with his iron, starting at the right and moving left. (continued...)

Comment: @Hearth (...) Each time he touched a pin just a little solder would melt and wick to the joint. Then he'd touch the next one, which melted just a little more solder. It worked fast and easy with no solder wick required. (Of course, whenever I try it I still need a little wick sometimes) :)

Comment: @hacktastical I mixed up QFP and QFN! QFPs are a little tricky but I can solder them with some effort; it's QFN that I don't know how to do.

Comment: @Hearth QFN is pretty easy with hot air. You put down paste, heat it up and let it reflow. Without hot air is tricky, but basic hot air goes for less than a decent soldering iron on Amazon or various Chinese sites.

Comment: @Hearth Solder bead on a bevel tip with untinned sides gets under the QFP to the solder pad. It is nearly impossible to see if good contact was made though without a microscope because so little solder is involved. Also, alignment needs to be correct the first time as soon as the first pin is soldered because you can't remelt for realignment without hot air which is the main weakness of this method. Go real slow and careful tacking it down.

Comment: @Hearth:  QFN is the same.  Fine tip, small diameter solder, pad by pad.

Comment: @Hearth This is how I do it: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/502238/6102

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your soldering technique...

If you're using solder wire (I recommend 0.25mm) it's easy to solder 1206, 0805 takes several solder attempts to get handy with, 0603 is still possible, but for most cases it's best to have microscope, 0402 is doable, but insanely hard.

If you're using paste, then I'd go for 0603 as default, because it's quite easy to solder it using pan/sand or oven technique.

So in general: buy one of those SMD kits that are used to learn soldering and try to do it. Most of it will have various size components. Like [this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/SMD-Rotating-LED-SMD-Components-Soldering-Practice-Board-Skill-Training-Kit-DIY/192343157603?hash=item2cc88bab63:g:-vIAAOSw3b9cdjlY) one.

And I recommend to swap to paste as soon as possible, it's way easier (if you have proper tools). Benefit of paste is that you can solder whole board at once :)

Comment: Then 0201 must be impossible.  Except I do 0201 by hand with a regular soldering iron - no microscope or magnifying glass.  Just my crummy old myopic eyes.

Comment: @JRE For me it's impossible, because I've big defect of vision, which makes it quite hard already at 0402 (myopia), but after I swapped to paste I use soldering iron only to desolder some components or fix connections after reflow.

Comment: My eyes suck.  Seriously.  I need glasses to see far enough away to see the computer screen. I can't see anything farther away than about six inches without my glasses.  I take my glasses off and make use of my short sightedness.

Comment: @JRE I can't focus on anything farther than 2" without my glasses. It's so close that I almost can't focus on it.