# Training Kit for SMD components

Tags: soldering, surface-mount

I created my first circuit with a microcontroller, an stm32f446 in lqfp64 package. However I have soldered such tiny parts and I'm struggling a bit and already destroyed one of three chips I bought.

Is there any kind of training kit? I do not want to spend each time 10 bucks for training purposes.

Comment: Yes there are. Have you searched for them?

Comment: YouTube it..  get a hot plate and hot air tool low velocity heat gun and practice. Or use an oven or use other methods

Comment: Buy the cheapest IC and SMD parts on ebay you can find, and pratice with them. It doesn't matter what they do.
You can also buy some SMD to pin header boards for cheap to practice solder on.

Comment: Get an old motherboard and practice taking chips off and then putting them back on.

Comment: Motherboards are hard to start with due to the copper planes (they take a lot of heat before you can desolder from them). But for other electronics (2~4 layers), starting with "trash" it is a good recommendation.

Comment: I wrote down some QFP soldering advise here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/502238/6102

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buy the cheapest IC and SMD parts you can find on ebay, and pratice with them. It doesn't matter what they do.
You can also buy some SMD to DIP boards for cheap, that matches the IC package, to practice solder on.

[image: Adapter boards]

Comment: Well, perhaps not Ebay... if you get old parts with lots of oxide, they aren't gonna be very fun to solder even with generous amounts of flux.

Comment: Clean with pencil eraser.

Answer (score 0):

I used this for myself to get the hang of it. There's ton of SMT resistors and small chips and took me awhile to get it done.
Here [1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00VWB8F8K)

Also consider you might want to re flow solder your final project.